# Horizontal Line which takes up less than 100% width

Tags: html, css, line

I know that a border can be used in lieu of the horizontal line tag (`hr`). However, in this case I don't want the line to take up **100% width**; the current `div` does and so would the border if I were to put a border in.

So I would like to put a horizontal line (`hr`) in with **80% width** but it's not showing up, well specifically the width is not **80%**. The place at which I want to insert it is the very first line after the `bottom` class in my code.

My intention is to put the horizontal line (`hr`) right above the **Cola** (`<p class="center1">Cola</p>`) on the page. Also the styling doesn't seem to work either here for the `hr` class; trying to put a width and a color on it.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: green;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#subnav {
  height: 10%;
  text-align: center;
}
#subnav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#subnav li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#subnav li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#subnav li a:hover {
  color: yellow;
}
#subnav li a:active {
  color: yellow;
}
#bigwrap {
  height: 100%;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.top {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
}
.bottom {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.bottom {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  height: 50%;
}
hr.style1 {
  border-top: 1px solid #8c8b8b;
  width: 80%;
}
.top {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  height: 50%;
}
.topa {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-left: 3%;
  width: 45%;
  height: 100%;
}
.topb {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.advisory {
  background-color: white;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
#advisory ul li {
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
.center1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: green;
  font-size: 28px;
}
.tpoint {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="subnav">
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="#">Sam </a>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Sam </a>
      </li>
      <li> <a class="active" href="#">Corn </a>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Sam </a>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Sam </a>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Sam </a>
      </li>
      <li> <a href="#">Sam </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="top">
    <div class="topa">
      <img src="ham.jpg" width="209" height="205" alt="Picture of kid" />
      <img src="bacon.jpg" width="209" height="205" alt="Picture of kid\" />
    </div>
    <div class="topb">
      <h2> Sams </h2>
      <p>Sample sentence this Sample sentence this Sample sentence this Sample sentence this Sample sentence this Sample sentence this Sample sentence this Sample sentence this Sample sentence this Sample sentence this Sample sentence this Sample sentence
        this Sample sentence this Sample sentence this Sample sentence this Sample sentence this Sample sentence this Sample sentence this Sample sentence this Sample sentence this Sample sentence this Sample sentence this Sample sentence this Sample
        sentence this Sample sentence this Sample sentence this Sample sentence this</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="sam">
      <hr class="style1">
      <p class="center1">Cola</p>
      <p class="center tpoint">Sample</p>
      <ul>
        <li>Sample
          <ul>
            <li>Sample</li>
            <li>rsam</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>san
          <ul>
            <li>sam</li>
            <li>sam</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>sam
          <ul>
            <li>sam</li>
            <li>sam</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>sam
          <ul>
            <li>sam</li>
            <li>sam</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>sam
          <ul>
            <li>sam</li>
            <li>sam</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <p class="center tpoint">The sam</p>
      <ul>
        <li>sam
          <ul>
            <li>sam</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>sam</li>
        <li>sam</li>
        <li>sam</li>
        <li>sam</li>
        <li>sam</li>
        <li>sam</li>
        <li>sam</li>
      </ul>
      <p class="center tpoint">Eggs</p>
      <ul>
        <li>sam
          <ul>
            <li>san</li>
          </ul>

        </li>
        <li>Eri
          <ul>
            <li>Sam</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your line's parent is the div `sam`, which has a width of 134px. By setting the `hr` width to 80%, you're telling it to be 80% of 134px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may modify your `CSS` as following:

Add width **100%** to the class `sam`:

```
.sam {
   width: 100%;
}
```

Add *centering* to the class `style1`:

```
.style1 { 
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `hr`is inside a container that has a smaller width (div `.sam`), so it's width is 80% of that container. Just move it up in the HTML code, above the `.bottom` div:

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
}
body {
 background-color: green;
}
html,
body {
 height: 100%;
}

#subnav {
 height: 10%;
 text-align: center;
}
#subnav ul {
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 background-color: red;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 font-weight: bold;
}
#subnav li {
 display: inline-block;
}
#subnav li a {
 display: block;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
#subnav li a:hover {
 color: yellow;
}
#subnav li a:active {
 color: yellow;
}
#bigwrap {
 height: 100%;
}
.container {
    display: flex; 
    position: relative;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch; 
    min-height: 100vh; 
    width: 80%; 
 margin: 0 auto;
 background-color: white;
 font-size: 20px;
}

.top {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 justify-content: flex-start;
 align-items: center; 
}
.bottom {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 justify-content: space-around;
 align-items: flex-start;
}
.bottom {
 flex: 0 0 100%;
 height: 50%;
}
hr.style1{
 border-top: 1px solid #8c8b8b;
 width: 80%;
}
.top {
 flex: 0 0 100%;
 height: 50%; 
}
.topa {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: column wrap;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: flex-start;
 margin-left: 3%;
 width: 45%;
 height: 100%;
}
.topb {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 justify-content: center;
 align-content: center;
 width: 50%;
 height: 100%;
}
 
li {
 list-style-type: none;
 font-size: 18px;
}
.advisory {
 background-color: white;
 margin: auto;
 width: 100%; 
}
#advisory ul li {
 margin-bottom: 2%;
}
.center {
 text-align: center;
}
.center1 {
 text-align: center;
 color: green;
 font-size: 28px;
}
.tpoint {
 font-size: 24px;
 color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
     <div id="subnav">
            <ul>
       <li> <a href="#">Sam </a></li>
          <li> <a href="#">Sam </a></li>
       <li> <a class="active" href="#">Corn </a></li>
       <li> <a href="#">Sam </a></li>
             <li> <a href="#">Sam </a></li>
                <li> <a href="#">Sam </a></li>
                <li> <a href="#">Sam </a></li>
      </ul>
       </div>
     <div class="top">
         <div class="topa">
          <img src="ham.jpg" width="209" height="205" alt="Picture of kid" /> 
      <img src="bacon.jpg" width="209" height="205" alt="Picture of kid\" /> 
            </div>        
         <div class="topb">
             <h2> Sams </h2>
             <p>Sample sentence this Sample sentence this Sample sentence this Sample sentence this
                Sample sentence this Sample sentence this Sample sentence this Sample sentence this
                Sample sentence this Sample sentence this Sample sentence this Sample sentence this
                Sample sentence this Sample sentence this Sample sentence this Sample sentence this
                Sample sentence this Sample sentence this Sample sentence this Sample sentence this
                Sample sentence this Sample sentence this Sample sentence this Sample sentence this
                Sample sentence this Sample sentence this Sample sentence this  </p>
         </div>
        </div>
             <hr class="style1">
        <div class="bottom">
         <div class="sam">
             <p class="center1"> Cola </p>
             <p class="center tpoint"> Sample </p>
                <ul>
                 <li> Sample
                     <ul>
                         <li> Sample </li>
                            <li> rsam </li>                       
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li> san
                     <ul>
                         <li> sam </li>
                            <li> sam </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li> sam 
                     <ul>
                         <li> sam </li>
                            <li> sam </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li> sam
                     <ul>
                         <li> sam </li>
                            <li> sam </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li> sam
                     <ul>
                         <li> sam </li>
                            <li> sam </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
           <p class="center tpoint"> The sam</p>
                <ul>
                 <li> sam
                     <ul>
                         <li> sam </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li> sam  </li>
                    <li> sam </li> 
                    <li> sam </li>
                    <li> sam </li> 
                    <li> sam  </li>
                    <li> sam </li>
                    <li> sam </li> 
                </ul>
                <p class="center tpoint" > Eggs </p>
                <ul>
                 <li> sam 
                     <ul>
                         <li> san </li>
                        </ul>
                    
                    </li>
                    <li> Eri
                     <ul>
                         <li> Sam </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Oh thanks. I have a question, so before I did that I accidentally put it right before 'sam' but after 'bottom', and it completely through everything into wack. Even though I know it's wrong, why did it do that? It also wasn't centered. I corrected it using your version but I just want to know why that mistake is the way it is. -Thanks

Comment: As I wrote: The `hr`was inside the `.sam` div, so it was centered inside that div, and it was only 80% of that DIVs width wide.

Answer (score 1):

The `hr` is inside `.sam` div which is not getting full width. That is why you are seeing the `hr` with small `width` (but it is taking 80% width).

```
.sam{
   width:100%
}
```

This will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**try it**

```
<hr align="left" width="50%">
```

Answer (score -1):

You have mistake in the markup

If you want horizantal line 100% width

change  `<hr class="style1">` to    `<hr class="style1"/>`

This fixes it

Comment: Direct quote from OP: "...in this case **I don't want the line to take up 100% width.**"

Comment: Also, when using anything other than the XHTML DOCTYPE, you don't have to close self-closing tags.